# Row is sum of 3 latest values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, row

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'values':[2,6,1,5,8,9]})
```

I'm trying to create a new rom called `sum` that is the sum of the 3 latest values. So it would return this `[np.nan, np.nan, 9, 12, 14, 22]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with [`Rolling.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.sum.html):

```
print (df.rolling(3).sum())
   values
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     9.0
3    12.0
4    14.0
5    22.0
```

Or:

```
print (df['values'].rolling(3).sum())
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     9.0
3    12.0
4    14.0
5    22.0
Name: values, dtype: float64

df['sum'] = df['values'].rolling(3).sum()
print (df)
   values   sum
0       2   NaN
1       6   NaN
2       1   9.0
3       5  12.0
4       8  14.0
5       9  22.0
```

[Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#window-functions-are-now-methods).

Answer (score 1):

With focus on performance, here's one approach using [`NumPy's 1D convolution`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) -

```
np.append([np.nan]*2,np.convolve(df['values'],np.ones((3,)),'valid'))
```